# How get bandwidth consumption from an Icecast server by user ip?

Tags: php, icecast, quota

everybody,
I'm working on a personnal project, and I want to know the bandwitdh usage for each IP(user) connected to my server.

I want to do something like this :

```
IP                PORT       BandWidth       Quota       Connection_time
192.168.1.10       8000       988,478 Gb      1,000 Gb    720:01:20.956
192.168.1.12       8001       98,478 Gb       1,000 Gb    01:01:20.956
192.168.1.216      8003       9,784 Gb        1,000 Gb    00:59:25.545
```

Do you have an idea ?

---

I have many Icecast (webradio streams) on my server, and I want to know the consumption of each listeners of each radio

My main focus, is to display the bandwidth consumption of the user on its profile, and too to check if he has reached his quota or not.

Comment: I would suggest to use some tools such as bmon or nload. It applys rather to device and not to particular user...

Comment: Okay, but my goal is to check if the user has reached his limit or not.
Also, I want to display its consumption on its profile.

Comment: You first need to define exactly what a user is, and what kind of bandwidth consumption you're measuring. Mostly likely PHP isn't involved in a lot of that bandwidth, so some hook into the web server which does the actual serving is needed. And that depends on the actual web server.

Comment: Alright, I have many Icecast (webradio streams) on my server, and I want to know the consumption of each listeners of each radio.

Comment: You may want to update your question with that extremely crucial information…

Comment: Ok , I add this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend parsing the Icecast `access.log` as it both logs the volume and duration of a connection.

You can also use the URL-authentication hooks to log things.

Comment: Thank you, but my icecast's access.log looks like this : 168.X.X.36 - - [28/Aug/2017:02:44:01 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1399 "-" "-" 0
158.X.X.126 - - [28/Aug/2017:23:41:41 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1399 "-" "-" 0

Comment: yes, that means `1399` bytes were transferred in `0` seconds. Which is not surprising, given that it's the status page.